# What are the differences between a car battery and other smaller batteries?

Tags: batteries

I'm not understanding why there's a small 9V battery while a giant car battery is only 12V.  Is a car battery 12V b/c it's enough to supply the whole car while getting recharged for prolonged time or is there a different reason why a car battery is 12V?

Comment: The voltage is not the only important thing about a battery. The car battery is much bigger because it has a much higher energy capacity and discharge rate.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is chemistry, and size. A 9V Battery is typically an alkaline battery made up of 6x 1.5V nominal cells. A car battery is typically a lead acid battery made up of 6x 2V cells or piles.

Lead Acid cells are bigger, heavier, and designed for high current over short time applications. Their chemistry is very dangerous or corrosive to humans and not well suited for consumer use. Sulfur and brimstone.

Alkaline batteries are better at low current over a longer time, weigh less, and are generally safe even when leaking. It won't eat through you like sulfuric acid would. Perfect for consumer products. You could get 12V alkaline batteries, like for garage door openers, but the capacity is low. All those batteries are, are multiple single 1.5V cells in series. 9V batteries sometimes have multiple AAAA sized cells inside. Smaller than AAA cells.

Comment: OTOH, SLAs aren't deliberately designed to eat through their casing.

Comment: Their weight makes them impractical in most portable consumer battery situations though. SLA are limited to emergency lights, UPS, and older car jump starters or cardiac defibulators (both which are moving to lighter Lithium packs), in portable consumer level products.

Answer (score 2):

A Car battery has a low internal resistance, on the order of a few milliohms. It can deliver hundreds or even thousands of amps into a short circuit, and many kilowatts into a low impedance load (like the starter motor of a car).

A 9v battery (or at least the one I just tested) has an internal resistance of about 5 ohms, it can deliver about 10 watts in the best case (with about the same lost as heat in the battery).

The difference is due to the construction and chemistry of the batteries. The electrodes of a car battery have a large surface area and the acid salt solution allows free movement of ions within the cell, whereas a 9 volt alkaline battery uses small electrodes and a paste-like electrolyte which does not allow the ions the same mobility.